Telegram bot geolocation
I'm creating telegram on Node js bot that should keep information of user's routes and give statistics:
1 - Max speed
2 - Avg speed
3 - How long
...
may be show route on the map in future.
I need to get user's location real time. I tried to it in my React part (Telegram mini apps) but it doesn't work when app minimized (in background mode)
How can I listen geolocation when user's device blocked?

Telegram allows to share location on lifetime, you can do the same in any chat just tap paperclip button, choose location, and there will be an option of sharing it some time. Once you choose it, it will send a message with your current location and will periodically edit the same message, changing longitude and latitude when you move automatically. I haven't tested it on blocked phone, but you can try

Thank you. Can you show me code example?
